# Read multiple files

Tags: c++, file-io, console-application

I'm new to c++ and am trying to alter the console app code posted below to read multiple files, ideally using a wildcard extension. Can some please give me some pointers..?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916815#odc_wssusageeventlogging_examiningtheusagelogfileformat

-----------Edit-------

What I need is how to change the code above instead of pointing it to a specific [filename.log] point it to a directory name and let it process all the log files in that directory.

--------------Tools-----

Win32 Console Application project in Visual Studio 2010 in C++

[To be run on win 32 bit platform]

Comment: File names can't contain wildcard characters on most if not all file systems. What platform are you using and what do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: 1) Take all of that hideous code in `main` and put it in a function, 2) have main iterate through the (multiple) file names passed in as arguments and invoke the function, 3) figure out how to handle wildcards. Which part do you need help with?

Comment: i will have to rewrite into functions later. I need help with the multiple files e.g point at a directory and let the code read all the files contained in there.

Answer (score 1):

Using Win32 APIs you can list the files in a directory by following [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  From there it should be relatively trivial for you to incorporate that code into your application to allow you to process multiple files as requested.

Specifically the [FindFirstFile API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows for wildcard when search for files.

Comment: Thanks Chad this, alls good except my arguments are type char and i need to change one of them to TCHAR 'argv[1]' is this possible?

Comment: There are non-unicode versions of the APIs that take in char*.  TCHAR as used in the example is just a Microsoft specific typedef that will either be `char` for ASCII executables or `wchar_t` for Unicode executables.  If you're building with the ASCII character set (under Project->Properties->General) then you will get the `char` typedef automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use the boost library check out 
[this post](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/74944). If you're using something like C++/CLI then there is support in .NET for this as well (I'm assuming for now you're not using C++/CLI). If you specify the tools at your disposal maybe you can get a more directed answer.

Comment: Hi Todd, I'm using a Win32 Console Application using Visual Studio 2010 in C++